Backward pass of Softmax with CrossEntropy
I'm trying to calculate the Softmax backward pass;
fn softmax_backward(&self, logits: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    let probability = self.forward(logits);
    let mut derivative = vec![0.0f32; probability.len()];

    for i in 0..probability.len() {
        for j in 0..probability.len() {
            if i == j {
                derivative[i] += probability[i] * (1.0 - probability[i]);
            } else {
                derivative[i] -= probability[i] * probability[j];
            }
        }
    }

    derivative
}

but it doesn't seem to work. The (cross-entropy) gradients are multiplied with the derivative after they are returned, and therefore omitted in the for-loops.
fn layer_backward(
    &self, gradient: &Vec<f32>, input: &Vec<f32>, output: &Vec<f32>
) -> (Vec<Vec<f32>>, Option<Vec<f32>>, Vec<f32>) {
    let derivative: Vec<f32> = self.softmax_backward(output);
    let delta: Vec<f32> = mul(gradient, &derivative);

    let weight_gradient: Vec<Vec<f32>> = delta
        .iter().map(|d: &f32| input
        .iter().map(|i: &f32| i * d)
        .collect())
        .collect();
    let bias_gradient: Option<Vec<f32>> = match self.bias {
        Some(_) => Some(delta.clone()),
        None => None,
    };
    let input_gradient: Vec<f32> = (0..input.len())
        .map(|i: usize| delta
            .iter().zip(self.weights.iter())
            .map(|(d, w)| d * w[i])
            .sum::<f32>())
        .collect();

    (weight_gradient, bias_gradient, input_gradient)
}

I've tried searching a fair bit (as well as asking ChatGPT etc.), without any luck. The loss is constant, and the gradients seem to always become 0.0, (when it shouldn't).

I seemingly fixed it by subtracting the dot product (as per source):
fn softmax_backward(&self, logits: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    let probability = self.forward(logits);
    let mut derivative = vec![0.0f32; probability.len()];
    let dot = probability.iter().map(|&p| p * p).sum::<f32>();

    for i in 0..probability.len() {
        for j in 0..probability.len() {
            if i == j {
                derivative[i] += probability[i] * (1.0 - probability[i]) - dot;
            } else {
                derivative[i] -= probability[i] * probability[j] - dot;
            }
        }
    }

    derivative
}

